# How to use uboot test command 'or' -o option

Tags: u-boot, test-command

From the output below it appears that the command does not work with integers, or the true and false commands, so what is the intended use of `test -o` (or) command?

```
=> version
U-Boot 2017.01 (Apr 01 2021 - 00:00:00 +0000)
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc (GCC) 9.3.0
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.34.0.20200220
=> if test 0 -o 0; then echo yeehaw; else echo yeenaw; fi
yeehaw
=> if test 1 -o 0; then echo yeehaw; else echo yeenaw; fi
yeehaw
=> if test 0 -o 1; then echo yeehaw; else echo yeenaw; fi
yeehaw
=> if test 0 -o 0; then echo yeehaw; else echo yeenaw; fi
yeehaw
=> if test 1 -o 1; then echo yeehaw; else echo yeenaw; fi
yeehaw
=> if test false -o false; then echo yeehaw; else echo yeenaw; fi
yeehaw
=> if test true -o false; then echo yeehaw; else echo yeenaw; fi
yeehaw
=> if test false -o true; then echo yeehaw; else echo yeenaw; fi
yeehaw
=> if test true -o true; then echo yeehaw; else echo yeenaw; fi
yeehaw
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string is considered true if it's non-empty, and false if it's empty:

```
$ if test ""; then echo true; else echo false; fi
false
$ if test "x"; then echo true; else echo false; fi
true
```

It follows that `test "" -o x` is true. You can also use `-o` between more complex comparisons:

```
# Make sure 0 < $x < 10
if test "$x" -le 0 -o "$x" -ge 10; then echo "out of range"; fi
```

However, POSIX recommends using the portable shell construct `||` instead of relying on the legacy operator `test -o`.

Comment: Which, to be clear, means that with the above examples, U-Boot's hush is acting like a normal shell would (as all of the provided examples provide "yeehaw" on bash, for example).